# Problem expanding arguments

Tags: expansion, ifthenelse

I have a problem of understanding how expanding works.
I have been reading several posts but none of them solve my problem.

I have been trying to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\exploregroups \expandarg
\StrFindGroup{{{a}}}{1,1}[\foo]
\ifthenelse{\equal{\foo}{a}}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\end{document}
```

"Of course", it returns FALSE. I suppose that it is because of not expanding the argument \foo.
However, I have tried:

```
\edef\fooE{{\foo}}
\ifstrequal{\fooE}{a}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

But still does not work. I have tried things with \expandafter and so but I have not been able to make them work.

Comment: It is because `\foo` is defined as `{a}`, so you only get TRUE with `\ifstriequal{\foo}{{a}}`.

Comment: Welcome! What's your precise aim? Maybe there are better ways to accomplish it. Solving the particular problem is not difficult, but…

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual, `\StrFindGroup{{{a}}}{1,1}` returns `{a}`. You can remove the braces by passing the expansion of `\foo` to a one argument macro that returns the argument unbraced.

You can test it by adding `\texttt{\meaning\foo}` after defining it, which would print

```
macro:->{a}
```

Here's an example of what you can do.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\iden}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\exploregroups \expandarg
\StrFindGroup{{{a}}}{1,1}[\foo]
\edef\foo{\expandafter\iden\foo}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\foo}{a}}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\end{document}
```

This prints

> TRUE